# redirect a new user after registration to some page while send them some email

Tags: laravel

I was trying all of the step from this site :

https://vegibit.com/how-to-send-email-to-new-users/

and find some problem in the route, **"loginUsingId(1)"** it'll call user id 1 from database and I wan to change it with auto increment. So after a new user registered their self and their data was putted through database they will be taken to this page -> **/member** and got an email notify.

```
$user = \Auth::loginUsingId(1);
Route::get('/member', function () use ($user)  {
    \Mail::to($user)->send(new welcomeMail($user));
    return view('member');
});
```

Here is my registercontroller.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use App\Mail\welcomeMail;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::MEMBER;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'phone' => ['required', 'numeric', 'min:11'],
            'asal_instansi' => ['required', 'string'],
            'usia' => ['required', 'integer'],
            'pekerjaan' => ['required', 'string'],
        ]);
    }
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_maganger';

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'phone' => $data['phone'],
            'asal_instansi'=> $data['asal_instansi'],
            'usia' => $data['usia'],
            'pekerjaan' => $data['pekerjaan'],
        ]);
          \Mail::to($user)->send(new welcomeMail($user));
    }
}
```

and here's my database table

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
          $table->bigIncrements('id_maganger');
          $table->string('name');
          $table->string('email')->unique();
          $table->boolean('is_admin')->default(0);
          $table->bigInteger('phone');
          $table->string('asal_instansi');
          $table->bigInteger('usia');
          $table->string('pekerjaan');
          $table->string('password')->default("");
          $table->rememberToken();
          $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

this is my App/User.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'asal_instansi', 'usia', 'phone', 'pekerjaan', 'is_admin'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */

     public function setpasswordAttribute($value)
     {
       $this->attributes['password'] = ($value ?: str_random(6));
     }

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_maganger';

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

Can someone please help me with this? Thank you

Comment: loginUsingId(1) is just an example. It is there just to be sure you have User class instance available. Instead, for real world example you would like to put this block of code (Mail class sending) just after user has been registered in RegisteController (there where you get `$user` variable).

Answer (score 1):

Save the id when you create the new user in a variable `$new_userid` then you just will have to call `$user = \Auth::loginUsingId($new_userid);`.

Comment: sorry before, which file should I change to save the variable? is it in migrtions table or where? and how do I write it

Comment: Migrations are only for manipulating the structure of the db. You should be looking for a controller which insert the new user, I don't know which authentication middleware you are using, if it is Laravel's default, it will be located in `app >http>Controllers>Auth`

Comment: hey Gamopo, i already edit the question, please help me where should I initialize the variable of $new_userid I'm a new progammer tho